Proving $\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}7\right)^{1/3}+\cos\left(\frac{4\pi}7\right)^{1/3}+\cos\left(\frac{6\pi}7\right)^{1/3}=(\frac{5-3\cdot 7^{1/3}}2)^{1/3}$
I have been tasked with proving:
$$\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right)^{1/3}+\cos\left(\frac{4\pi}{7}\right)^{1/3}+\cos\left(\frac{6\pi}{7}\right)^{1/3}=\left(\frac{5-3\cdot 7^{1/3}}{2}\right)^{1/3}$$
I found the above in MathWorld's "Trigonometry Angles -- Pi/7" entry, labeled as an identity with source: Borwein and Bailey 2003, p. 77. Simply googling the source doesn't yield much to go off.
How do I go about proving this?
I have tried using unity roots methods outlined in the Math.SE question "Exact values of $\cos(2\pi/7)$ and $\sin(2\pi/7)$".
Any help appreciated.
Ps. I am a physicist

This is just wrong. To get a correct equation, you need to use the correct signs to refer to the principal branches of the cubic roots, as in the Weisstein link.

I plugged the numbers into the Python REPL, and got $(1.088895998652042+1.8860231938237877j)$ for the LHS and $(0.35875753982497+0.6213862865752628j)$ for the RHS.  So the two sides aren't equal.  Not with the principal definition of the 1/3 power, anyway.

However, the math does check out if you define the cube root of negative numbers as $\sqrt[3]{-x} = -\sqrt[3]{x}$.  Then it's numerically equal to $-0.7175150796499399$, the sole real solution to $4x^9 - 30x^6 + 75x^3 + 32 = 0$.

Motivation: find a polynomial with roots $\cos(2\pi/7)$, $\cos(4\pi/7)$, $\cos(6\pi/7)$. I provide some steps. If you are stuck, feel free to ask although I have included as many details I could.

Consider the seventh roots of unity $f(x) = x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$ with roots $x = \cos(2k\pi/7) + i\sin(2k\pi/7)$ where $k\in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

It follows that setting $t= x+\frac1{x}$ gives us that $f(x) = x^3(x^3 + \frac1{x^3} + x^2 + \frac1{x^2} + x + \frac1{x} + 1)$. Use that $x^3+1/x^3 = t^3-3t$ and $x^2+1/x^2 = t^2-2$. Thus $f(x) = x^3(t^3 - 3t + t^2 - 2 + t + 1)$. So setting $f(x) = 0$ gives that $t^3+t^2-2t-1 = 0$. This polynomial in $x$ has the roots defined as above but in $t$ the roots are just $x+\frac1{x}$ which is $2\cos(2k\pi/7)$ where $k\in \{1,2,3\}$. Set $t\mapsto 2t$ to get the polynomial with the correct roots, viz. $8t^3+4t^2-4t-1=0$

Let us denote each of the cosines by $x^3,y^3,z^3$ respectively. Recall the identity $a^3+b^3+c^3 - 3abc = (a+b+c)((a+b+c)^2 - 3ab - 3bc - 3ca)$. Setting first $(a,b,c) \mapsto (x,y,z)$ and $(a,b,c) \mapsto (xy,yz,zx)$, where $x+y+z = P$ and $xy + yz + zx = Q$; we get the following two equations:


$$\begin{align}
(x^3 + y^3 + z^3) - 3(xyz) &= P(P^2 - 3Q) \\
(x^3y^3 + y^3z^3 + x^3z^3) - 3(x^2y^2z^2) &= Q(Q^2 - 3Pxyz)
\end{align}$$
All the elementric symmetric polynomials in $x^3, y^3, z^3$ can be evaluated using the polynomial mentioned in point $2$, leaving us two equations in $P$ and $Q$.
Now solve for $P$. One must be careful of what branch of the cube root is chosen for finding $xyz$ and $x^2y^2z^2$ from $x^3y^3z^3$ which is known.

Rendering the result explicitly, we have

$$x^3+y^3+z^3=-(1/2)$$
$$xyz=1/2^*$$
$$x^3y^3+x^3z^3+y^3z^3=-(1/2)$$
$$x^2y^2z^2=1/4^*$$
(*-- this comes from the real cube-root branch of $x^3y^3z^3=1/8$, which is chosen to assure consistency with the real values assumed in the original sum.)
So
$$Q=P(P^2+2)/3$$
$$-(5/4)=\dfrac{P^2+2}{3}\left(\left(\dfrac{P^2+2}{3}\right)^2-\dfrac{3P}2\right)\implies 4P^9-30P^6+75P^3+32=0$$
This may be solved by the Cardano method for $P^3$, giving only one real value for $P^3$, viz.
$$P^3=\dfrac{5-3\sqrt[3]7}{3}$$
from which the claimed result follows.

Apologies- I am not good at LaTeX, so I am writing on a paper. And hopefully my handwriting is readable.
My Working Here
You can try to find a cubic whose solution is $2\cos \frac{2\pi}{7}$,$2\cos \frac{4\pi}{7}$ and $2\cos \frac{6\pi}{7}$.
On the way to the cubic, you may get $2\cos \frac{2\pi}{7}+2\cos \frac{4\pi}{7}+2\cos \frac{6\pi}{7}=-1$ and other equations useful.
I haven't finished the calculation part, but I am sure this method will give you an answer.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

COMMENT.-It is known (not much however) that $\cos\left(\dfrac{2\pi}{7}\right),\cos\left(\dfrac{4\pi}{7}\right)$ and $\cos\left(\dfrac{6\pi}{7}\right)$ are roots of the polynomial
$8x^3+4x^2-4x-1=0$. Since the exact form of these roots are complicated, we have an approximation:
$$\cos\left(\dfrac{2\pi}{7}\right)\approx0.623489801859\\\cos\left(\dfrac{4\pi}{7}\right)\approx-0.222520933956\\\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{7}\right)\approx-0.900968867902$$ Of course, this values can be obtained without the above cubic equation. After this, make the corresponding numerical calculation to verify the equality. If you want to have the proof with exact forms you must try with non elementary mathematics.
